# tomcat 8 in Eclipse Luna failed to start : Error with directory [C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse\lib]

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I need your help.

I'm new on eclipse. (I have been used Intellij until now)I installed java,tomcat,maven and finished all integrations and configurations.

I created maven project on Eclipse Luna but when I want to debug I get an this error message.

```
WARNING: Problem with directory [C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse\lib],
exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead:[false]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:465)
```

Do you know How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your project as a Dynamic web project or if the project is already created add the faced to it by doing:

Right-click the project --> Properties --> Project Facets --> check the Dynamic Web Module facet --> OK.

Comment: it didn't solve. I created project as a maven project. I couldn't see Dynamic Web Module fecet on Project Facets

Comment: Did yo configure the project to use facets? When you click on Project Facets you will see a link which says Convert to faceted form... and clicking on them will show the list of facets available.

Comment: But you see some facet?

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem and here's how I solved it.

I went to "Run -> Run Configurations" and selected the problematic server under "Apache Tomcat". After that, I selected the "Arguments" tab and changed the working directory from the default to where I had Tomcat installed (for me it was in an opt dir)